# Expand row given criteria

Tags: r, duplicates, row

I would like to insert a duplicate row if a column has a given value. I have the following dataset:

```
dataset <- data.frame(id=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
             date=c('2018-05-09 11:30','2018-10-28 01:15','2018-10-28 01:30','2018-12-08 14:15','2018-05-09 11:30','2018-10-28 01:15','2018-10-28 01:30','2018-12-08 14:15'),
             amount=c(10,20,22,14,12,24,26,10)
             )

    id  date                amount
1   A   2018-05-09 11:30    10
2   A   2018-10-28 01:15    20
3   A   2018-10-28 01:30    22
4   A   2018-12-08 14:15    14
5   B   2018-05-09 11:30    12
6   B   2018-10-28 01:15    24
7   B   2018-10-28 01:30    26
8   B   2018-12-08 14:15    10
```

And I wish to duplicate the rows that contain a given date, and divide the amount by 2. The dates to find are:

```
date_change <- c('2018-10-28 01:00','2018-10-28 01:15','2018-10-28 01:30','2018-10-28 01:45')
```

And I should get:

```
    id  date                amount
1   A   2018-05-09 11:30    10
2   A   2018-10-28 01:15    10
3   A   2018-10-28 01:15    10
4   A   2018-10-28 01:30    11
5   A   2018-10-28 01:30    11
6   A   2018-12-08 14:15    14
7   B   2018-05-09 11:30    12
8   B   2018-10-28 01:15    12
9   B   2018-10-28 01:15    12
10  B   2018-10-28 01:30    13
11  B   2018-10-28 01:30    13
12  B   2018-12-08 14:15    10
```

I tried using `expandRows` available in `splitstackshape`. But it only shows the replicated rows.

```
library(splitstackshape)
fixed <- expandRows(dataset[dataset$date %in% date_change,], 2, count.is.col = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *base* you can first find the places where `date_change` hits `date` with `%in%`. Divide their values by 2 and replicate those rows with `rep`.

```
i  <-  dataset$date %in% date_change
within(dataset, amount[i]  <- amount[i]/2)[rep(seq_len(nrow(dataset)), i+1),]
#    id             date amount
#1    A 2018-05-09 11:30     10
#2    A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
#2.1  A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
#3    A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
#3.1  A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
#4    A 2018-12-08 14:15     14
#5    B 2018-05-09 11:30     12
#6    B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
#6.1  B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
#7    B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
#7.1  B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
#8    B 2018-12-08 14:15     10
```

When you change your line

```
fixed <- expandRows(dataset[dataset$date %in% date_change,], 2, count.is.col = FALSE)
```

to

```
fixed <- splitstackshape::expandRows(dataset, dataset$date %in% date_change+1, count.is.col = FALSE)
```

it should do what you want. But still `amount` need to be divided.

Comment: Maybe add the `package(splitstackshape)` for the `expandRows` methodology

Comment: Perfect @GKi. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here is an idea via `dplyr`. We create a logical variable that indicates whether a date is in `date_change`, and add 1 (`TRUE` + 1 = 2 and `FALSE` + 1 = 1). We then use that in two cases; first to divide the amount (either with 1 or 2)and then to `uncount` (i.e. expand the rows the amount of times mentioned by new var)

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>% 
 mutate(new = date %in% date_change + 1, 
        amount = amount / new) %>% 
 tidyr::uncount(new)
```

which gives,

> ```
>     id             date amount
> 1    A 2018-05-09 11:30     10
> 2    A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
> 2.1  A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
> 3    A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
> 3.1  A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
> 4    A 2018-12-08 14:15     14
> 5    B 2018-05-09 11:30     12
> 6    B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
> 6.1  B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
> 7    B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
> 7.1  B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
> 8    B 2018-12-08 14:15     10
> ```

Answer (score 2):

We can `filter` the `date` which is present in `date_change`, divide the `amount` by 2 and repeat the rows twice and bind the rows where `date` is not present in `date_change`.

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
  filter(!date %in% date_change) %>%
  bind_rows(dataset %>%
              filter(date %in% date_change) %>%
              mutate(amount = amount/2) %>%
              slice(rep(seq_len(n()), each = 2))) %>%
   arrange(id)

#   id             date amount
#1   A 2018-05-09 11:30     10
#2   A 2018-12-08 14:15     14
#3   A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
#4   A 2018-10-28 01:15     10
#5   A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
#6   A 2018-10-28 01:30     11
#7   B 2018-05-09 11:30     12
#8   B 2018-12-08 14:15     10
#9   B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
#10  B 2018-10-28 01:15     12
#11  B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
#12  B 2018-10-28 01:30     13
```